# Update/Create Currency exchange rate in Power Automate from data in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate, dynamics-365

I created a power flow, where I get the latest exchange rates (Currency Code, Exchange Rate, Date) from a http request and update the currency rates. Update works fine, but there is the case of initialization of the currencies. When the currency will be created from this flow, I have to fill the below fields
[image]

But I want to use the Currency Name, Currency Symbol and Currency Precision from the following system table:
[image]

How this system table called, and how can I access to it?